# What's the procedure to set up username/password on mongodb?

Tags: mongodb, authentication

I have tried setting up username / password .But none of the methods seems to work.

```
1. In mongod.conf ----> remove **#auth=true** to **auth =true**


2.Started the mongod server --> sudo service mongodb restart


3. Created the user in --> use admin -->db.createUSer()
Followed these procedure still not able to figure out how it works its not working.

mongod --auth
```

But then I try to connect its opening with out any username password error.

I have checked many documentations and answers but was still not able to figure out.

Answer (score 3):

Create an admin to create users:

```
> use admin
> ( rs.initiate() )
> db.createUser({user:"siteUserAdmin",pwd:"password",roles:[{role:"userAdminAnyDatabase",db:"admin"}]})
```

Login as userAdmin:

```
$ mongo -u siteUserAdmin -p password --authenticationDatabase admin
```

Create an admin for the cluster:

```
> use admin
> db.createUser({user:"replSetManager",pwd:"password",roles:[{role:"clusterManager",db:"admin"}]})
> db.auth(replSetManager,password)
> rs.status()  -> ok
```

Create a user that can access all databases but not admin:

```
> use admin
> var w = { user:"will", roles:["readWriteAnyDatabase"], pwd:"abc"}
> db.createUser(w)
```

Create a user only for the test database:

```
> use test
> var a = { user:"joe", pwd:"asdf", roles:["readWrite"]}
> db.createUser(a)
```

Many roles can be combined and you can create super admins. Information on all the built-in-roles: http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/built-in-roles/

(You can build your own roles also if needed: http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/manage-users-and-roles/#create-user-defined-role)